Subnet associations in AWS Route tables
What is this "Subnet Associations" in AWS Route tables? Do I have to add the subnets under "Explicit Subnet Associations" as well?
It is already under "Subnets without explicit associations" added automatically after creating  subnets.
I'm not sure if I understand this correctly.

Each subnet must be associated with a route table, which controls the routing for the subnet. If you don't explicitly associate a subnet with a particular route table, the subnet is implicitly associated with the main route table.

Does this mean "If I don't select explicit associations then when I create a new Subnet, the new Subnet will choose main routing table of the VPC by default"?


Main route table: The route table that automatically comes with your VPC. It controls the routing for all subnets that are not explicitly associated with any other route table.
Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html

A route table tells what happens to the traffic that exits the subnet. In the simplest scenario, it all goes to the Internet. But you can also connect other subnets.
Each subnet can have a route table. If you don't select one (explicitly), it uses the main one, by default.
